# javascript: What dom object is in a point on the screen?

Tags: javascript, dom, position

I want a JS function, that will tell me which dom object, is at a certin point on the screen, that is - the object that will be clicked, if the mouse was in this X,Y coordinate and clicked. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you need this info *without* mouse action? I.e. do you need to be able to call `findDomObject(300, 200)` even if the mouse is somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.elementFromPoint(x, y);` will help you get this. Now if you are using mouseevents then you can proably replace x and y with the mouse position. Check http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html for mouse positions compatibilty in different browsers or use jQuery.

Comment: oh god! why didn't I chance upon [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) before. Learn something new every day.